# How to align expandable divs to the side of an always centred / centered element - css

Tags: html, css, css-float

I would like to create a page with a logo that is always horizontally dead centre and upon opening the page before anything is clicked on is also vertically centred.

I have created the page with the logo centred using simple margins:

```
margin: auto;
position: absolute;
top:0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
```

This works great with a full page background, but I would like to have a number of small 50px square divs to the right of the logo that will have icons for login, mail, info and if someone clicks on those divs they expand to show login fields etc.

[image]

Now the problem I have is I am very used to using 2/3 column layouts but I have no idea how to keep the logo dead centre if the div next to it expands.

(I dont mind if the logo moves up the page as the div next to it expands or whether the logo stays dead centre and the div expands downwards.)

This does not have to be compatible with anything before IE9

Comment: I have a solution although to my eyes it's quite ugly and looks bad practice. I put Div1 and Div2 inside of a the logo and positioned them relative to it:

http://jsfiddle.net/cqp5uufL/

Answer (score 0):

I may not fully understand your question but have you considered displaying the logo as a `background-image:`?

If that's not the solution you're looking for you should consider placing the logo in the first column of a table, and the boxes on the right in a second column of that table. Then vertically and horizontally center that table.

If you don't want to use a table you can achieve something similar with divs.